# Is there a way to configure Olingo to include the full entity url instead of name in the service document for "url"

Tags: odata, olingo

Created a sample OData service by following the steps outlined at the Apache Lingo tutorial.
The default Service Document received by the client is:

```
    "name" : "Products",
    "url" : "Products"
```

My requirement is to provide entity collection url in the service document as below

```
    "name" : "Products",
    "url" : "http://localhost:8080/DemoService/DemoService.svc/Products"
```

Didn't find option to provide complete url for entity.